# Limit decimals numbers when writing to csv in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, decimal

I loop over files and for each of these files, I compute a list of 4000+ (fixed number) features on it. These features are computed by a function and returned as `numpy.array`

I want to write a CSV file with one line per file (each line is one `numpy.array`with 4000+ elements).

I'm currently using the `csv`library of Python and even if my array is rounded (thanks to `np.around`), the CSV file contains numbers with a lot of digits, e.g. `0,302499999999999`instead of `0,3025`

I know this may come from [floating points limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) in Python, but i wanted to know if there is any way to avoid this (by writing it as a string?) in the output file.

Sample of code below to reproduce the issue :

```
import numpy as np
import csv

for i in range(10) :
    row = np.around(np.random.random(4000), decimals=5)

    with open('output.csv', "ab") as fp:
        wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.savetxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt) like this:

```
import numpy as np

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fh:
    for i in range(10):  # loop over features
        row = np.random.random(4000)
        np.savetxt(fh, row.reshape(1, -1), fmt='%.5e', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Thanks, and is there a `'a'` mode for `np.savetxt` ? Using your alternative i can only see the last `row` in the CSV. The CSV is written as if i've used the `'w'` mode in the `csv` library

Comment: Finally solved it using `with open('output.csv', "ab") as fp:
        np.savetxt(fp, row.reshape(1, row.shape[0]), fmt='%.5e', delimiter=',')`. Thanks !

Comment: @Julian: I updated my answer to better fit to your use-case